# Centering title of toolbar while working with BottomNavigationView and jetpack

Tags: android, toolbar, bottomnavigationview

1. Home screen (first time loading)

[image]

2. Navigating to 2nd option from the bottom navigation

[image]

To center the title on the ActionBar for each selected screen/fragment (as working with BottomNavigationView) I created the custom toolbar to hide the default title and display it at the center of the toolbar, code given below.

XML part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".bkk_revamp.home_screen.HomeScreenActivity">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_box"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

            <requestFocus />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/app_navigation" />
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_navigation_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Activity code:

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
titleToolbar = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.title_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, drawerLayout);

navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
            if(destination.getId()== R.id.profileFragment || destination.getId()== R.id.settingsFragment){
                bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            titleToolbar.setText(toolbar.getTitle());
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

it works well on app loading but as another option is clicked from the bottom navigation the default screen label also starts appearing, how can display only one title and at the center of the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried this?

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Comment: same result, still getting the double title names